# Widget moved visually, but responds to touch in the old location only

Tags: android, user-interface, layout

I'm implementing a sliding **from top** drawer custom widget from some source code (AFAIR, from sephiroth). It works well as is, but I need a small layout (i.e. 3 buttons) in the **handle** of the drawer. So, I had to modify the code a little. I'm using **dispatchTouchEvent** in the main onTouchEvent of the widget, to propagate the necessary events down to the children of the **handle** view.

It works well when the drawer is closed (the handle and its buttons are on the top of the screen), but when it is open all the way down handle buttons stop working. I have a proper response on touch from the handle layout frame (its color changing and I can close the drawer) though.

By an accident I've realized that handle buttons can be triggered by touching their old locations near the top of the screen! But their images are properly shown at the bottom, and react to the setText() properly. What's happening? And how to fix that?